# Is it possible to go out after going to the Metaverse?

Tags: persona-5

After exploring the Metaverse, I'm too exhausted to do anything, meaning I can't do anything that night. The later Palaces ramp up in difficulty quite a bit, so I've found myself spending more days in the Metaverse to clear them out, which drastically limits the times I'm able to do things at night. Is there any way to cure my exhaustion so I can still go out after going to the Metaverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily, there *is* a way to cure exhaustion in Persona 5. After reaching the maximum rank for the Temperance Confidant, you unlock the ability to get a massage after traversing the Metaverse during the day, which allows you to go out that night.

You unlock the Temperance arcana Confidant on 5/24 and you will need at least rank 2 Guts to start the Social Link.

It's worth noting that while this Confidant is only available to spend time with on Friday and Saturday nights, you are able to get a massage on **any** night.